# zend pass variable from controller to form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, parameter-passing, controllers

i'm developing an app and i'm trying to pass a variable from the controller to the form but without success. I need this variable for executing queries and populate fields of the form.

This is my code:

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$cod = $this->_getParam('cod');
        $form = new Application_Form_MylacForm($cod);
```

**FORM:**

```
public $_codanagrafica;
    protected $_codcircuito;

    public function __construct($codanagrafica = null, $param)
    {
        $this->_codcircuito = $param;
        echo $this->_codcircuito;
        $this->_codanagrafica = $codanagrafica;

        $this->init();
        $this->loadDefaultDecorators();
    }
```

With this code the variable **_codcircuito** is null.

How can i solve it?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing only one variable to form object:

```
$form = new Application_Form_MylacForm($cod);
```

And then you set _codcircuito with second argument, which is not passed:

```
$this->_codcircuito = $param;
```

$param is null in your case. Try:

```
$this->_codcircuito = $codanagrafica;
```

instead.

Comment: Thank's, i've removed the param "codanagrafica" and now it works.... Thank's a lot